# Simple pagination in FreeMarker with Spark Framework

Tags: pagination, freemarker, spark-framework

I implement a simple blog use Spark Framework with FreeMarker. I need implement pagination in order to show only 5 entries per page, and it is not necessary to show page numbers, with next and previous buttons would be fine. However, I don't even know where to begin in the pagination. This my current code to show all the entries:

```
<#list entries as art>
    <h2>
        <a href="/Entrada/${art_index}">${art.getTitle()}</a>
    </h2>
    <p>
        Author: <a href="">${art.getAuthor().getName()}</a>
    </p>
    <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>${art.getDate()}</p>
    <hr>

    <#assign body=art.getBody()>
    <#if body?length &lt; 70>
        ${body}
    <#else>
        ${body?substring(0,70) + "..."}
    </#if>

    <br><br>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/Entrada/${art_index}">Read More<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>

    <hr>

</#list>
```

Also, here is the backend code in Spark Framework:

```
get("/Home", (request, response) -> {

    Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>();
    attributes.put("entries", entrie.getEntries());
    return new ModelAndView(attributes, "index.ftl");

}, freeMarkerEngine);
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: If you found solution, can you please share how you are doing

Answer (score 0):

Usually you paginate before putting the list into the model, because then you can avoid loading the entries that you won't show anyway. So simply only pass the list of entries that you will actually show on the current page (as opposed to the whole list), and also pass a `pageNumber` and `totalPages` variable (two numbers) that you can use in the template.

BTW, in the template, `art.getAuthor().getName()` can be written as `art.author.name`. `body?substring(0,70)` can be written as `body[0 .. 70]`.